# can not identified widget?

Tags: android

Can anyone please let me know what widget is this? Please refer to the attachment for the widget in question.

It is launched from the messaging app, when I click on a received message.

It shows the text as the application name. I have searched for the term 'Messaging', but to no effect.

Thanks,[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a `Toast` message; it is an `AlertDialog`

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity {
    public final static int DIALOG_ERROR = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR); //this will call: onCreateDialog()
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_ERROR:
        //create dialog
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Messaging").create();
        break;
    default:
        //create a default dialog
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Toast` message with a custom `View`. [This tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView) can help you create your own.

[image]

For more on customizing a Toast object, check out [this other tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-toast-tutorial).

Comment: Toasts are not displayed with a grayed/dimmed Background.... Its certainly a custom dialog/alertbox. I'm not the one who down-voted. I was also about to answer like you...

Comment: But if you look at the `Toast` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView), it is centered on the screen, has corners, and is obviously customized. You can even customize the background color.

Comment: Then show a customized one with exactly the same look and feel... If you can't then you have to accept... It is not a TOAST.. it is a custom dialog or AlertDialog... You cannot grey-out an application (app that displays the toast). While graying/fading is the default behavior for dialogs and alerts.